# Doing an SQL Update with an Inner Join

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to update a field in the user table using an inner join with another table, but it does not seem to be working. I am using the code below:

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE U SET User.firstname = @Firstname FROM dbo.User AS U INNER JOIN dbo.Driver AS D ON U.userid = D.driverid WHERE D.driverid = @Driverid");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = firstname;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Driverid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = driverid;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

SQL:

```
UPDATE
  U 
SET 
  User.firstname = @Firstname 
FROM 
  dbo.User AS U 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Driver AS D ON 
    U.userid = D.driverid 
WHERE
  D.driverid = @Driverid
```

I am getting the following error:

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'

Where could I be going wrong? Thanks

Comment: UPDATE dbo.User AS U INNER JOIN dbo.Driver AS D ON U.userid = D.driverid SET U.firstname = xxx WHERE D.driverid =xxx

Comment: Not working = error message or not getting the results you want? Looks quite strange that you're updating from a table but you're not fetching anything from the table. Maybe exists is the correct operator to use?

Comment: I tried using the ones you guys told me to try but I keep getting :

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.

Comment: try using 'U.firstname = @Firstname'

Comment: Another solution that could result in better performance using EXISTS:

    `UPDATE dbo.[User] AS U
    SET 
      U.firstname = @Firstname 
    WHERE
      U.userid = @Driverid AND EXISTS (SELECT D.driverid dbo.Driver as D WHERE U.userid = D.driverid)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table `User` is defined/aliased as `U` in your selecting section, so thus reference it as `U` in the update fields list:

**EDITED**: 
Added square brackets around `User` which seems to be a reserved SQL keyword.

```
UPDATE
  U 
SET 
  U.firstname = @Firstname 
FROM 
  dbo.[User] AS U 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Driver AS D ON 
    U.userid = D.driverid 
WHERE
  D.driverid = @Driverid
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but I keep getting that same error at run time

Comment: It would read a lot more clearly as `UPDATE dbo.[User] SET firstname ...` @Khanh TO is really on the right track int the comment up there.